# How to save the output file in a directory and print the name of the output file?

Tags: perl, bash, unix, sudo, file-handling

I am parsing a file from which I then create multiple output files. I would like to save the output file(s) in a special directory in the same folder the perl script was executed from. If the directory already exists then put the files in that directory. If the user doesn't have sudo privileges then create the files in the current working directory.

```
use strict; use warnings;

sub main {
    my $directory = "pwd/test.pl_output";

    unless(mkdir $directory) {
        return 0; # unable to create directory (it either already exists
                      # or you don't have sudo privileges)  
    } else {
        return $directory
      }
}

if ( my $PATH = main() ){
    open(my $fh, '<', 'input.txt') or die $!;
    open(my $output, '+>', $PATH.'/output.txt') or die $!;
 } else {  # create the output file as usual
    open(my $fh, '<', 'input.txt') or die $!;
    open(my $output, '+>', 'output.txt') or die $!;
 }

 print "All done! Please look in \$output\n";
```

At the end of the script, after I have parsed and processed the file, I would like to print out the following to the shell prompt:

```
All done! Please look in 'output.txt' for the output.
```

If the output files are in the new directory, I would like to print the following:

```
All done! Please look in 'output.txt' in the directory '~/path/to/output.txt' for the output.
```

My code doesn't work.

Comment: I am not used to perl, but i do have a question here, `'$PATH/output.txt'` in this, $PATH, will it get replaced with it's value inside a `'`?

Comment: abasu That's another good catch.  Single quotes don't interpolate.  I suspect we're not seeing the actual copy-paste code.

Comment: I know it's possible to [create a directory in perl](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/perl/perl-mkdir-how-to-create-directories-in-perl/). But I don't know if the rest of what I'm trying to do is possible.

Comment: It is possible.  But the logic you're describing is more complex than the code you're showing.  In other words, your conditionals aren't handling all the conditions you mentioned.  And your use of 'pwd' is incorrect.  Just use the FindBin module instead, and the executable's path will be in `$FindBin::Bin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were several serious problems with your existing code.  One is your use of `pwd` inside of a double-quoted string.  That just won't work.  You *could* use `pwd` inside of backticks and capture the output, but not inside of a double quote literal.

Another problem is that the logic of your code doesn't approach the complexity of the description of how you would like to gracefully degrade destinations.

The following code snippet will first look for a directory named "special" within the executable's directory.  If it doesn't exist, it will try to create it.  If creation fails (probably due to permissions), it will next look for a directory named "special" in the user's current working directory.  If it doesn't exist, it will try to create it.  If that fails, it will die with a descriptive message.

If it runs past this point, then the "special" directory either pre-existed or has been created along one of the permissible paths.  Next, the files are opened.  If opening the output file fails, we die.  Otherwise, continue and presumably write to the file.  Then close both the input and output files.  Finally, print the path at which the output file may be found.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin;
use File::Path qw( make_path );

my $special_dir = 'special';
my $filename    = 'my_file.txt';


my $bin = $FindBin::Bin;

my $path;


if( not defined( $path = get_path( "$bin/$special_dir", "./$special_dir" ) ) ) {
  die "Unable to find or create a suitable directory for output file.";
}

my $output_filename = "$path/$filename";


open my $in_fh, '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;
open my $out_fh, '+>', $output_filename or die $!;

# Do whatever it is you want to do with $in_fh and $out_fh....

close $out_fh or die  $!;
close $in_fh  or warn $!;

print "All done! Please look in $output_filename for the output.\n";



sub get_path {
  my @tries = @_;
  my $good_path;
  for my $try_path ( @tries ) {
    if( -e $try_path and -d _ and -w _ ) {          # Path exists. Done.
      $good_path = $try_path;
      last;
    }
    elsif( eval { make_path( $try_path ); 1; } ) {  # Try to create it.
      $good_path = $try_path;                       # Success, we're done.
      last;
    }
  }
                                                    # Failure; fall through to
                                                    # next iteration.  If no
                                                    # more options, loop ends
                                                    # with $path undefined.
  return $good_path;
}
```

I'm using the Perl module FindBin to locate the executable.  And File::Path is being used to create the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Several time in past, I found it better to use perl script with Shell script for such purpose. Perl scrip for parsing and shell scripts for folder processing. And easily include the perl script with shell script. It would be more easy and handy.